# When a UUID token is revoked, how is it deleted from the client cache?

Tags: token, uuid, pki, keystone

When validating a token, if it is found in the client cache, it will be used directly without more validation needed, right?

For PKI token, there is an option named "**check_revocations_for_cached**" in section `[keystone_authtoken]`, but the comments says:

> This requires that PKI tokens are configured on the Keystone server.

So, only when PKI type token is used, the revocation list will be checked for the cached token, right?

1. What about the UUID token? When revoked, it will be deleted from the token backend, how about the token found in the cache?
2. in `/etc/nova/nova.conf`, section `[keystone_authtoken]`, there's a option named `cache` with this comment:

   > "Env key for the swift cache"

   I don't quite understand what this option 
   is, could someone help give me more explanation, pls?